# HTML5 <video> element not working in Firefox, Opera, and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, safari, opera

I have a HTML5 `<video>` element that runs perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox nor in Opera.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="tele">
    <video id="v" width="254" height="204" autoplay>
    <source id="mp4" src="/media/joies.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
     <source id="ogg" src="/media/joies.ogv" type="video/ogg" />         
     <source id="webm" src="/media/joies.webm" type="video/webm" /> 
     <object id="flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        data="player.swf?file=joies.mp4">
        <param id="flash2" name="movie" value="player.swf?file=joies.mp4" />
    </object> </video>


</div>





<ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="activo"
                    onClick="changeVideo('/media/joies.ogv','/media/joies.mp4','/media/joies.webm','player.swf?file=joies.mp4','player.swf?file=joies.mp4','<?php echo __('Col·leccions. Música de Kaiserama. Compositor Oscar Kaiser.')?>')">1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"
            onClick="changeVideo('/media/CanalTE.ogv','/media/CanalTE.mp4','/media/CanalTE.webm','player.swf?file=CanalTE.mp4','player.swf?file=CanalTE.mp4','<?php echo __('Joies Corrents. Música de Kaiserama. Compositor Oscar Kaiser')?>')">2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"
            onClick="changeVideo('/media/FAD.ogv','/media/FAD.mp4','/media/FAD.webm','player.swf?file=FAD.mp4','player.swf?file=FAD.mp4','<?php echo __("Enjoia\'t 06. Orfebres Fad.")?>')">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And JavaScript code:

```
function changeVideo(v,x,w,y,z,tit) {
    var presentationImg = "presentationImg";
    var presentationImg2 = "presentationImg2";
    document.getElementById("mp4").src=x;
    document.getElementById("ogg").src=v;    
    document.getElementById("flash").data=y;
    document.getElementById("flash2").value=z;
    document.getElementById("webm").src=w;
    document.getElementById("titol").innerHTML=tit
    var video = document.getElementById('v');
    video.load();
    video.play();
    }
```

To visit the website: http://www.saradomenech.com/ca/zapping
Where is the problem?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try to put *ogg* element first in video tag.

```
<source id="ogg" src="/media/joies.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
```

Comment: ok thanks then run all, but the menu to change video not work in Safari. Some solution?

Comment: sorry, can't help you with it. No safari on my PC.

Comment: now I have a problem in local runs and in server not in frefox? when is the problem? thanks

Comment: Sorry but in your pc runs with firefox?

Comment: I have removed the flash path and not works. Sorry now to visit the site is: http://saradomenech.com/ca/zapping